# Automatically Update Firebase Firestore Field Value at Scheduled Intervals

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database structure is something like this:

```
    if (user.dayLimitNow === user.perDay) {
          console.log("Daily connection limit reached. Quitting...");
    
          user.dayLimitNow = 0;
          await updateDayLimitNowInFirebase(user, user.dayLimitNow);
          return;
        }
    
        if (user.dayLimitNow >= user.perDay) {
          console.log("Daily connection limit reached. Resetting for 12 hours...");
    
          const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
    
          if (currentHour >= 17 && user.dayLimitNow === 0) {
            console.log("Bot can send connects after 5 PM, next day.");
            user.dayLimitNow = 0;
            await updateDayLimitNowInFirebase(user, user.dayLimitNow);
    
          } else {
    
    
            console.log("Bot cannot send connects at this moment.");
            user.dayLimitNow = 0;
            await updateDayLimitNowInFirebase(user, user.dayLimitNow);
            return;
    
    
          }
    
          console.log("Day limit reset. Quitting...");
          return;
        }
```

Here the "user.dayLimitNow" reset the value to 0 at 5pm every day.I want to change the value of field "dayLimitNow" from 'any value' to '0' exactly at 5pm every day. The bot will close automatically. Is there any way to do so?

if there is something do with so is it paid or free ?